# Question about sets under the metric $(X, |x-y|)$

Tags: metric-spaces

If we let $X = [1, 3] \cup (4, \infty)$ and we consider the metric $(X, |x-y|)$, is $A = [1, 3]$ open? **That is counter-intuitive to me,** but I seem to have proved it is, as follows:

1. For the interval $(1,2)$ choose $\epsilon = |1-x| = x-1$. Then it is clear that $2x-1 > y > 1$, and then $B_\epsilon(x) = (1,3) \subseteq A$.
2. For the interval $(2,3)$ choose $\epsilon = |3-x| = 3-x$. Then it is clear that $3 > y > 2x-3$, and then $B_\epsilon(x) = (1,3) \subseteq A$.
3. For $x = 2$, choose $\epsilon = 1$. Then $B_1(2) = (1,3) \subseteq A$.
4. For $x = 3$, choose an arbitrary $0 <\epsilon \leq 1$. Let's say $\epsilon = 1$. Then $B_1(3) = (2, 4) - (3,4) = (2,3] \subseteq A$, because the interval $(3,4)$ is not in $X$.
5. For $x=1$, choose an arbitrary $0< \epsilon \leq 2$. Let's say $\epsilon = 1$. Then $B_2(1) = (0, 2) - (0, 1) = [1, 2) \subseteq A$, because the interval $(0, 1)$ is not in $X$. $\blacksquare$

---

**OBS.** I graduated in physics long ago and I'm trying to learn some rigorous math to understand GR better. ;) Any hints will be useful.

Comment: Yes, note that $[1,3]$ is the open ball $\{x\in X:\ |x-1|<5/2\}$ that has center $1$ and radius $5/2$.

Comment: $Y\subset (X, d) $ . Then $A\subset Y$ is open in $(Y, d_Y) $ iff $A=Y\cap U$ for some open set in $(X, d) $.

Comment: $[1, 3]=([1, 3] \cup (4, \infty)) \cap (0, 3.5) $

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all this. You can prove it directly from the definition.

An open neighborhood of $x\in X$ is a set $S(x,\epsilon)$=

{$y\in X :\,d(y,x)<\epsilon$}. (For some $\epsilon>0$)

A set $B$ is open if for each $x\in\,B$ there is an open neighborhood of $x$, such that $S(x,\epsilon)\subseteq\,B$. For

$x\in (1,3)$ the result is obvious. For $x=1$

the neighborhood $S(1,\epsilon)$={$y\in X : d(1,y)<\epsilon$} i.e.{$y\in X :|1-y|<\epsilon$} and taking $\epsilon=\dfrac{1}{2}$ we obtain $S(1,\epsilon)$=$(\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{2})\bigcap[1,3]=[1,\dfrac{3}{2})$$\subseteq\,[1,3]$. Likewise for $x=3$. Thus $[1,3]$ is open!